# Criando um foreach com resultado de uma query vinda do Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Olá, estou tentando fazer um foreach com um resultado da query,  o campo que preciso percorre é uma string, porem na hora que passo para o foreach ele está sendo transformado em outro valor.

Preciso comparar duas data, no caso a conversão do campo String para DateTime está dando erro, por que como citado acima o campo esta sendo modificado na hora que passa no foreach.

Segue abaixo o código na PageModel:

```
var tp = _context.TarifasPrecosItens.Where(p => p.TarifasPrecosId == tx.Id).First();

foreach(var hora in tp.De)
{
    DateTime horaInicial = Convert.ToDateTime(hora);
    DateTime horaCliente  = Convert.ToDateTime(totalPermanencia);

    if (horaCliente > horaInicial)
    {
        PagamentoTarifaUsada = tx.Descricao + " Acima de " + hora;
        Tarifa = tp.Valor;
        Total = tp.Valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é **De**? é uma lista? se sim, do que é? o erro acontece em qual das duas conversões do `foreach`? de onde vem a variável **totalPermanencia**?

Comment: O De é um campo que vem da tabela, no caso ele tem um valor de "01:00" só que depois que passa para o foreach ele é transformado em "48" ai no caso o erro da conversão.

Comment: ` var tp = _context.TarifasPrecosItens.Where(p => p.TarifasPrecosId == tx.Id).First();`
Você não está pegando apenas um registro?

Comment: Desculpa... Não entendi o que quer fazer, se o campo "01:00" e você passa ele pelo `foreach`, vai retornar **"0", "1", ":", "0", "0"**, ou seja, vai retornar cada char separado, [Veja aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8pPklU)

Comment: Lucas, no caso tp recebe vários registro da tabela, no caso tp.De e um campo, porem em tem vários valores retornado da consulta.

Comment: Barbertta, verdade vc está certa, preciso tranformar em uma lista antes de passar para o foreach, porem também preciso pegar o valor de um outro campo, na posição onde parar no if. Sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @mba, redija sua pergunta da forma na qual você quer resolver seu problema. Você já sabe que o `foreach` não é o problema que você quer resolver, mas sim pegar propriedades de `TarifasPrecosItens`. **Quais** itens de `TarifasPrecosItens`? **Quais** propriedades? **O que** você quer fazer com elas? **Para que** elas serão usadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Não deixei resposta antes porque estava muito corrido.</sub>

O problema ocorre porque você está retornando um único item de valor "01:00" e ao passar esse valor pelo `foreach` irá retornar cada `char` da `string`, você pode ver um exemplo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8pPklU).

Para retornar uma lista, remova o `First()`

```
var tp = _context.TarifasPrecosItens.Where(p => p.TarifasPrecosId == tx.Id);
```

Outra coisa que faria é utilizar o `TryParse` para fazer a conversão, como ele é possivel fazer um tratamento caso ocorra algum erro, você pode usa-lo mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach (var item in tp)
{
    DateTime horaInicial;
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(item.De, out horaInicial))
    {
        //Tratamento erro
    }

}
```

A partir do C# 7 é possível simplificar o `TryParse` da seguinte forma

```
DateTime.TryParse(item.De, out DateTime horaInicial)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito - veja bem, eu **creio**, porque, pela descrição, não dá pra entender o problema - que o que você quer fazer é o seguinte:

```
var tp = 
    _context
        .TarifasPrecosItens
        .Where(w => Convert.ToDateTime(w.TotalPermanencia) > Convert.ToDateTime(w.De)); 

foreach (var item in tp)
{
    item.PagamentoTarifaUsada = $"{item.Descricao} acima de {item.De}";
    item.Tarifa = item.Total = item.Valor;
}

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Fala @Marcelo Uchimura, como você pegou a conversa andando ai ficou meio estranho mesmo. Mas a duvida inicial era sim do foreach, por que ele estava mudando o valor, mas como você mesmo disse já resolvi, não marquei a resposta da Barbertta como resposta por que foi um comentário. Mas estarei excluindo esse post para que ninguém mais tente resolver está questão. Obrigado pela resposta. Abraços.